# Screenshot Lock not working in React native app on iOS devices

Tags: react-native, screenshot, screen-capture, screenshotexception

We want to lock screenshot on app screens in React Native app so that user is not allowed to take  the screenshot. The feature is implemented successfully in android version of the same React Native app. But it is not working in iOS app which is published to app store. I have also tried react-native-prevent-screenshot plugin but that is also not locking screenshot in iOS version. I even implemented blurred view on appDelegate.m file to prevent screenshot capture in app, but even this did not have any impact. Can someone tell if Apple has banned this feature completely or there is possibility of some issue in coding. But I rule that out because it is working successfully in android apk. Please help

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Comment: I read at some online places that screenshot lock can not be implemented in apps to work on iOS devices now due to Apple's policies. I want to know is that correct ?

Comment: Use the [instabug-reactnative](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instabug-reactnative/v/8.5.2) package to catch bugs in the application and update this post to provide a more detailed bug report.